# Probability that random cubic polynomials meet in a square

Tags: pr.probability, polynomials, plane-geometry

Let $p_1(x)$ and $p_2(x)$ be cubic polynomials with
random coefficients in $[-1,1]$.
I wanted to compute the probability that $p_1$ and $p_2$
share at least one point within
the square $[-1,1]^2$.
Of course this is the same as the probability that
$p_1(x)=p_2(x)$ for $x \in [-1,1]$ and $p_1(x) \in [-1,1]$.
I am not seeing this as a straightforward computation
based on known root distribution results for random polynomials,
but I admit to ignorance in this area.
Crude experimentation suggests the probability might not be
far from $\frac{1}{2}$.
Below, $5$ out of $9$ instances meet within the $[-1,1]^2$ square.

 
 
 
[image: PolyInt3x3]

My interest derives from graphics and cubic splines.
I wanted to understand how likely it would be that the
(relatively expensive) root computation would be necessary
to compute certain graphic representations, e.g., visibility 
from above.

Comment: I simulated 100,000 cases, and the result in the form of {# of zeros, frequency (%)} is as follows: {{0, 39.179}, {1, 48.567}, {2, 10.847}, {3, 1.407}} That is, about 40% of total cases had no zero.

Comment: For what it's worth, this is exactly a question about the number of roots in [-1,1] of a random cubic with coefficients taken from a "witch's hat" distribution on [-2,2].

Comment: @Anthony Quas: That ignores the restriction on the $y$-coordinate. The graphs of $(x^3+3x)/3$ and $(3x^2+1)/3$ meet at $(1,4/3)$ which is outside $[-1,1]^2$.

Comment: Can one learn something from first doing the case of polynomials of lower degree? At least for affine functions, the problem should be much easier.

Comment: For affine functions, my simulations suggest an intersection probability in $[-1,1]^2$ of about 0.49.

Comment: Indeed, the Mathematica command `Probability[
 And @@ (-1 <= # <= 1 & /@ {x, a x + b} /. 
     Solve[a x + b == c x + d, x] // First), {a, b, c, 
   d} \[Distributed] 
  UniformDistribution[{{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]]` gives the exact result $47/96\approx0.48958...$.

Comment: @Eckhard: Surprising to see that not-quite-$\frac{1}{2}$ fraction! (The probability that two random chords of a circle cross is $\frac{1}{3}$.)

Comment: If you don't restrict the $y$-coordinate of the intersection then the probability for two lines is exactly $1/2$ by the involution swapping the linear and constant coefficients. The x-coordinate of the point of intersection of $\lbrace a_i x + b_i\rbrace $ is $-\frac{b_1-b_0}{a_1-a_0}$. The deficit from $1/2$ comes from the times the lines intersect with $x \in [-1,1], y \notin [-1,1]$ like $0.3 x + 0.9$ and $0.8 x + 0.5$ which intersect at $(0.8,1.14)$.

Comment: @DouglasZare: Nice, Douglas! But, still, a deficit of exactly $\frac{1}{96}$-th is amazing.

Answer (score 3):

If $p_i(x)=a_ix^3+b_{i,2}x^2 + b_{i,1}x + b_{i,2}$ for $i\in\{1,2\}$ then a sufficient condition for $\exists (x,y)\in [-1,1]^2$ with $y=p_1(x)=p_2(x)$ is that (writing $a=a_1-a_2$, $b_j=b_{1,j}-b_{2,j}$)
\begin{eqnarray}
\tag{1}\sum_{j=0}^2 |b_{j}|\le |a|\quad\text{and}\\
\tag{2}|a_i| + \sum_{j=0}^2 |b_{i,j}| \le 1\quad\exists i\in\{1,2\}
\end{eqnarray}
and this gives a **nonzero lower bound** of approximately $0.02$ on the probability (an 8-fold multiple integral which it is tricky to get Mathematica to do).

Indeed, it is easy to see that with probability 1 there exist $(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2$ with $y=p_1(x)=p_2(x)$; consider one such pair. If $|x|\ge 1$ then we have by (1)
$$
|ax|\le |b_2| + \frac{|b_1|}{|x|} + \frac{|b_2|}{|x|^2} \le \sum_j |b_j|\le |a|
$$
so $|x|\le 1$ after all. To ensure $|y|\le 1$ we use (2).

Comment: You can ask WolframAlpha to evaluate the probability of (2), via NIntegrate[ Boole[a + Abs[b] + Abs[c] + Abs[d] < 1], {a, -1, 1}, {b, -1, 1}, {c, -1, 1}, {d, -1, 1}]/16.  This gives 0.27, so your lower bound is between 0 and 0.27^2 = 0.073.  I similarly asked Mathematica to evaluate the 8-fold integral for (1) and (2), and it complained about slow convergence, saying: "NIntegrate obtained 0.02 and 0.04 for the integral and error estimates".

Comment: I also got about 0.02 using Mathematica, so I incorporated that into the answer.